# Pass variable to jquery modal, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code for JQuery UI modal window:

```
$('<p>Message</p>').dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
});
```

How can I pass a variable instead of constant string (see `Ok` above)

Comment: Lets say I have var x = "some string". How to pass it to look like x:function() {... etc

Comment: where do you want to pass a variable?

Comment: So your question should be: **How can I have custom buttons in a jQuery Dialog**

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery dialog button variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464843/jquery-dialog-button-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var dynamicButtons= {};
var buttonOne = 'Press Me Please!';
var buttonTwo = 'No way';
dynamicButtons[buttonOne] = function() {
    // do your stuffs
};
dynamicButtons[buttonTwo] = function() {
   // do your stuffs
};
$('<p>Message</p>').dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: dynamicButtons
});
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/omawu4/2/

Answer (score 1):

from [jQuery UI dialog button text as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464843/jquery-dialog-button-variable)

```
var button_name = 'Test';    
var dialog_buttons = {};

dialog_buttons[button_name] = function(){ 
    closeInstanceForm(Function); 
}    
dialog_buttons['Cancel'] = function(){ 
   $(this).dialog('close'); 
}

$('#instanceDialog').dialog({ 
    buttons: dialog_buttons 
});
```