# How do I change the text of Close button here?

Tags: jquery-ui

```
if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {
            $("#validation_dialog").dialog({
                title: "Form alanlarini kontrol edin!",
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                show: "blind",
                hide: "explode",
                buttons: {                        
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
```

I have this on my page, it works fine but where can I change the text of the "Close" button?

Comment: dupe?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464843/jquery-dialog-button-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify a name like here:

```
buttons: {                        
    "Some other name": function () {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not see that before :) I was looking blind hehehe, thx @Dmitry Tarasov